# Sort part of VARCHAR as INT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort on a part of string as integer by `CAST(pid AS SIGNED)` with no success.

I think I need something like this pseudocode: `CAST ON REGX('^islandora(/d?)$') OF pid AS SIGNED`

`doFields` table has following structure:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid           | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ownerId       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

here is sample data:

```
+----------------+---------+
| pid            | ownerId |
+----------------+---------+
| islandora:1050 | 8       |
| islandora:1052 | 8       |
| islandora:1053 | 8       |
| islandora:1054 | 8       |
| islandora:1055 | 8       |
+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: are all pid has `islandora` on it?

Comment: rows with `islandora` are importance for me, but a few rows has `default` instead of `islandora` and it is be very good if I could sort on them too in single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this ORDER BY -

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid, ':', -1) * 1;
```

Comment: this is what I need, but why this query is very slow and take 0.4 second to execute?

Comment: The query will be fast only when sort by indexed and not changed field is used. In this case we use string function to modify the `pid`, then MySQL sorts all records, so, indexes are not used. It is better to separate these two values to two different fields.

Comment: I can't modify table structure while it is an external database. is there any way to speed of this query?

Comment: If the string was like '1050:islandora', then you could use index length - 4. But I think it won't help you.

Answer (score 3):

how about replacing the word `islandora:` and casting it to int.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(pid, 'islandora:', '') AS SIGNED) ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
order by 
       cast(substr(pid,locate(':',pid)+1) as SIGNED)
```

if the integer part is always 4 letter length then

```
  Order by
      cast(right(pid,4) as SIGNED)
```

Comment: select cast(substr('islandora:1050',locate(':','islandora:1050')+1) as SIGNED)    retuns 1050, no error